# XSLT sort based on attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to sort the following 'testsuite' based on attributes of the childnodes. In this case 'executed'. How do I do that ?

This is my XML

```
 <test-suite name="AnalyticsRequestTest" success="True" time="0.003" asserts="0">
                    <results>
                <test-case name="IntegrationTests" executed="True"  success="True" time="0.002" asserts="1" />
  <test-case name="IntegrationTests1" executed="False"  success="False" time="0.002" asserts="1" />
```

And my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template name="testsuites">
      <xsl:variable name="lcletters">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="ucletters">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="//test-suite[(child::results/test-case)]">
         <xsl:sort select="child::results/test-case[translate(@executed,$ucletters,$lcletters)='false']" />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. But remember that xxl:sort/@select has to compute the sort key as a string or number (not a test-case element!). So I suspect

```
<xsl:sort select="child::results/test-case[translate(@executed,$ucletters,$lcletters)='false']" />
```

should be

```
<xsl:sort select="translate(child::results/test-case/@executed,$ucletters,$lcletters)" />
```